# Multiple Jquery UI Progressbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have multiple Progressbars on my website such as below, each must contain different values depending on the value I put on the value attribute. The code is working, however, it only gets the first value which is 40 and apply this value to all progressbar. I have posted the javascript as well below please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
<div value="40" class="progressbar"></div>
<div value="70" class="progressbar"></div>
<div value="90" class="progressbar"></div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: parseInt($(".progressbar").attr('value'))
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `each()` loop to keep reference on targeted element:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".progressbar" ).each(function(){
       $(this).progressbar({
          value: parseInt(this.value,10)
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works like a charm. I'll mark your answer correct in 10 min.